# How to input or estimate missing text data?

Tags: machine-learning, data-cleaning, missing-data, text

My task requires 32 different columns with 25 beeing independent text data.
Deleting nan values, or cutting columns which has less then 20% (of non NaNs) results in reducing dataset to less then 10% of samples.
How should i proceed?

According to lastly mentioned [How to impute missing text data?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/99545/how-to-impute-missing-text-data) We can just pass 0 or leave it missing, however in my case that would leave too many missing or the same data that it will influence results.
In cases where data is repeating (like names of countries) and with corelation with other column Is it worth to just input data according to current data distribiution (where we know over 50% of data)?